# Is there an alternative to require.toUrl in AMD?

Tags: requirejs, amd

Passing "require" as a module dependency allows you to get the location of a resource.

```
   define(["require"], function(localRequire){
      var pathToTheBarModuleInTheFooNamespace = localRequire.toUrl("foo/bar");
   });
```

Is there an alternative to do this without depending on "require"? Using this pattern makes the module depend on an AMD-specific feature, and not all build-tools like this (e.g. Webpack, almond, ...).

So, given the example above, how can I get the location of the "foo" package without using the require.toUrl method?